# Is it possible to get a user from a frequent_contacts id in a Telegram JSON export?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

After exporting data from Telegram in JSON, I can get a list of `frequent_contacts` where an `id` field is present.

It looks like this `id` isn't a normal `user_id`, because it has a different length. Maybe it's a `chat_id`?

Is it possible to get the `user_id` or `username` from this ID?

Here is an example of the data that I exported:

```
"frequent_contacts": {
  "about": ....,
  "list": [
  {
    "id": 4579257353,
    "category": "people",
    "type": "user",
    "name": "<User name and surname>",
    "rating": 101.039391
   },
```